# How to SELECT the minimal match from a database if not all fields have a value?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

So I apologize if this has already been asked before in a different way, but I have spent a few hours now thinking about this and searching it and have come up empty.

I have a simple database with 5 columns: id,Client,Subject,Location,MyText.  I need to grab the MyText column based off the best match.  So if a record exists with a client, subject, and location, then its clear which one to grab.

What I am unfamiliar with is what might be the best method for grabbing MyText if say only Subject and Location have a match, or Location and Client only, or even just Subject, etc.  What I had originally thought was to just run queries with the total number of possibilities that can exist, but not sure if there is a less resource intensive method.  Currently there are 7 possibilities to run, 8 if you consider no match found but that's pretty easy.

Hope that makes sense and any help is much appreciated.

UPDATE: So far the answers are yielding some results but still missing the mark.  So with the answers provided so far, I think maybe explaining the outcome a little better will help.

Say I have the following

```
Client = 4,
Subject = 16,
Location = 1500
```

I have records in the database for the following

```
id,client,subject,location,mytext
1,4,16,NULL,Client & Subject Only
2,4,16,1501,All fields have a value
3,4,16,1600,All fields have a value but are different
```

How can I make it select row 1 as the result when none of the others match?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MyText
FROM table
ORDER BY (Client = @Client) * @weightClient
        +(Subject = @Subject) * @weightSubject
        +(Location = @Location) * @weightLocation DESC
LIMIT 1
```

`@Parameter` is the parameter value provided for comparison.

`@weightParameter` is the weighting factor of the parameter - the more important the parameter, the greater the coefficient.

Comment: Interesting.  Can you help me understand the weighted parameter a bit better?  I tested this in SQL and I keep getting the result when all 3 fields are matching.

I tested this which I think should give me the MyText value when only the Subject and Location match.  Had to change the @ symbol to avoid stack overflow issues.

SELECT MyText
FROM table
ORDER BY (Client = AT14) * AT15
        +(Subject = AT35) * AT35
        +(Location = AT1667) * AT1667 DESC
LIMIT 1

Comment: @Born2Discover Weighting koeff. is a number which is large if the parameter equiality is more important and less if not. For example, if all parameters are approx. equal then all 3 koeff. may be 1. If Client is more important then Subject which is more important then Location then the keffs. may be 3,2,1... or 5,3,2..., if Client and Subject importance is equal then koeffs may be 2,2,1 or 4,4,1 or 1,1,2... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

In a generic way, you could create a "score" column in the select and sort result by this column.

```
SELECT id,
       client,
       subject,
       location,
       (IF(  client IS NULL, 0, 1) +
        IF( subject IS NULL, 0, 1) +
        IF(location IS NULL, 0, 1) ) AS matches,
       mytext
  FROM born2discover
  WHERE client   = <Client-Match>
     OR subject  = <Subject-Match>
     OR location = <Location-Match>
  ORDER BY matches DESC
  LIMIT 10
```

Watch out for the fact you can have more than one "best match" and you'll need to determine what to do about.

*This approach assumes "1" as weight for all fields.